# jQuery insert var in front of a push?

Tags: jquery, function, return, push

I have a puzzle that has gone beyond me as I thought I understood how this works but clearly I don't. The function below has `columns.push($('#squad'+count).val());` which contains `"Squad " +count` so you get `Squad 1 2 3 4 5 etc etc`. 
The next push contains names, `Bob, Joe, John, Mark, etc etc`.

So right now the below produces:

```
Squad 1|Bob,Joe,John,Mark|Squad 2|Cletus,Ray ray,Billy Joe|Squad 3|Fred,Barney,Wilma
```

I want it to output:

```
Squad 1,Bob,Joe,John,Mark|Squad 2,Cletus,Ray ray,Billy Joe|Squad 3,Fred,Barney,Wilma
```

I can't for the life of me figure this out. And I know its something simple but hours of searching has led me here. Any help is appreciated.

```
function getItems(exampleNr)
{
    var count = 0;
    var columns = [];
    $(exampleNr + ' ul.sortable-list').each(function(){
        columns.push($('#squad'+count).val());
        columns.push($(this).sortable('toArray').join(','));
        count++;
    });

    return columns.join('|');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're joining **Squad #** to the same `columns` array. The code you had before produced the result it did because `columns` is

- Squad 1
- Bob,Joe,John,Mark
- Squad 2
- Cletus,Ray ray,Billy Joe
- Squad 3
- Fred,Barney,Wilma

Which is why they were separated with pipes (`|`).

To fix it as you want it, you'll want **Squad #** along with the other names. You can achieve this by changing both `columns.push` lines to this one line:

```
columns.push( [$('#squad'+count).val()].concat($(this).sortable('toArray')).join(',') );
```

Effectively creating an array with the **Squad #** and concatenating the sorted ones at the end *before* joining them together with `,`.

Answer (score 0):

Just combine the two `push`s and place both data into one.

```
function getItems(exampleNr)
{
    var count = 0;
    var columns = [];
    $(exampleNr + ' ul.sortable-list').each(function(){
        columns.push($('#squad'+count).val()+','+$(this).sortable('toArray').join(','));
        count++;
    });

    return columns.join('|');
}
```